# Import and render raw volumetric data

Tags: rendering, import, volumetrics

Is it possible in Blender to import and render raw volumetric data (outcome of fluid simulator)?

I have a set of 3d arrays of floats in C/C++ and I used to render it frame by frame with OpenGL using splatting. Now I would like to use Blender ray traycer to get much more realistic results. I would like it to look like a dense smoke. It would be nice to have realistic looking shadows and lighting too.

I appreciate any help.

EDIT:

I suppose Voxel Data with 8 bit raw files is the way to go.

I found [this article](http://pythology.blogspot.com/2014/08/you-can-do-cool-stuff-with-manual.html). Following Leopold's comment gives me empty results. [My files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4c3kndz7f78v0c1/AABTEYyoZw3LOmf9hgb0m4rsa?dl=0). 
I feel I am close to the final solution, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Now, in the Blender 2.9x series, it is actually possible to import/export [openVDB](https://www.openvdb.org/) volume files in and out of the scene.

See [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/volumes/properties.html#openvdb-file) in the Blender manual for 2.91

In fact, there is even a [mesh to volume](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mesh_to_volume.html?highlight=convert%20volume) modifier for meshes in the scene, which is extremely helpful for rendering complex volumes in EEVEE without having to do serious procedural node working.